# fckeditor with ipad

Tags: html, ipad, fckeditor

I am using FCKEditor with desktop. And we have modified FCKEditor with specific requirements. Like rightclick on that FCKEditor will popup certain page and then selecting some text on that pop up page will be replaced that text on FCKEditor.

But now we need to make sure same functionality should work on our iPad.

I tried with various ways but not at all working. Do any one known anything regarding this?

Comment: There is no right click on iPad or iPhone or any other touch devices. You need to use touch events. What "various ways" did you try?

Comment: I tried for CKEditor a latest version of FCKEditor. As well tried with left click instead of right click. But can't implement same on FCKEditor. But thatnks for your answer "There is no right click on iPad or iPhone or any other touch devices". I was thinking as if there any way like... ? Basically I am using default safari browser of iPad and tried to make it work same as desktop. By the way you said touch events? it's nothing but a javascript right?

Comment: Apple Safari Web Content Guide. Check it out. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RightClick is not possible on ipad. So need to fire any ipad event instead of rightclick event(contextmenu). i have done it using gesturechange event of ipad it is working fine as well on ipad with same functionality of desktop.

For that you need to change in java-script file of fck-editor is fckeditorcode_gecko.js 
And first you need to add Event Listener to editor like

this._Document.addEventListener('gesturechange', FCKContextMenu_Document_OnContextMenu, false);

try it it will work, let me know in case of any query